# Decrease opacity of content when been scrolled under fixed navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I'm trying to make a nice transition of content from opaque to transparent under some div's (in ou case - footer and navbar) and keep their background transparent to avoid overlapping of content, as well as keeping general background of page as their background.

For example - here's our page:
[image: For example - we have this]

Currently, when we scroll - we have this;
[image]

But i want it in the way like this:
[image]

Take note: background of page could be a fixed gradient or wallpaper, not flat colour, and navbar/footer has no background.

How to do this?

---

**UPD:** In order to make things clear, here's the deal

[image]

As you see - solutions like "header with the same BGR and 100-to-0 gradient below header" won't work in this case, because header background won't match with page background when been vertically stretched. That's why i want to make a smooth decrease of opacity under the header/footer.
If it's at least possible to mask into the header and footer a background gradient of the same size as page's one - i welcome this. Maybe i will end up with throwing this idea away if there's no non-hardcore solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this I just made...

https://jsfiddle.net/5kmobuf7/2/

```
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #4b5852;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 30px 10px #4b5852;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
}

body {
  background-color: #4b5852;
  margin: 0;
}

#content {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Cheers Ryan - keep yours though I'd be curious to see how yours works. Mine won't work so well with background images etc so if you have a longer but more robust solution that'd be cool to see.

Comment: @FraserBenjamin the idea is right, but i need header/footer to have no own background, because yours will only work with flat backgrounds.

Comment: @FraserBenjamin Good idea! I have added it back :)

Comment: I haven't got time tonight to try it but you might be able to create the background as the same gradient and colour match the shadow so it blends in naturally but I'll have a think about a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Personally i would recommend using a gradient on the header

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/ve806t1a/

and here is the code that I used:

```
<p class="header">
HEADER
</p>
<div class="header-bg"></div>

<p>
CONTENT
</p>
<p>
CONTENT
</p>
<p>
CONTENT
</p>
<p>
CONTENT
</p>
<p>
CONTENT
</p>
<p>
CONTENT
</p>
<p>
CONTENT
</p>
<p>
CONTENT
</p>
<p>
CONTENT
</p>
<p>
CONTENT
</p>
<p>
CONTENT
</p>
<p>
CONTENT
</p>
<p>
CONTENT
</p>
<p>
CONTENT
</p>
<p>
CONTENT
</p>
```

css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgba(198, 115, 115, 1);
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: rgba(198, 115, 115, 1);
}
.header-bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(198, 115, 115, 1),rgba(47, 52, 172, 0));
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
```